# Evaluating integral e^z over a line

Tags: contour-integration

How do i evaluate 
$$ \int_C e^z dz $$

along the line y=x from (-1, -1) to (1, 1)

here $$ z = x+iy $$ since its a straight line, I have z = t where t goes from -1 to 1 ? How do I proceed after this ?

Comment: From the information you've given, either $z$ isn't complex or your coordinates should be $(-1, -i)$ and $(1, i)$. Then you can parameterise your curve $$x = t \implies y = t \implies z = (1+i)t \implies dz = (1+i)dt$$

Comment: So if t is from -1 to 1 wont that give me 0 as the answer ?

Comment: No, $e$ is not an even function. Compute the integral, see what happens.

Comment: I get 2sinh(1+i)